# Questions about useQuery and react-error-boundary package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, react-suspense, react-error-boundary

I want to use the react-error-bounary package and suspense to handle asynchronous handling in the asynchronous processing method using isLoading and isError, which are normally operating in useQuery. The code below is the code using the react-error-boundary package and suspense.

`Routers.tsx`

```
const chartError = () => (  //fallback component of errorBoundary
  <h1>error occur!</h1>
) 

function Router() { 
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      ...skip
      <Route path='chart' element={
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={chartError}>
          <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading</h1>}>
          <CoinChart/>
          </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      }/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

`coin_chart.tsx`

```
export function CoinChart() { 
  const {coinId} = useParams();

  //useQuery to call api inside CoinChart component
  const {data} = useQuery<IHistorical[]>(['coinHistory', coinId], () =>      fetchCoinHistory(coinId), {suspense: true, useErrorBoundary: true});
    
  return (
    <>
      {<Line data={coinData} options={options} />}
    </>
  )  
}
```

`coin_api.ts`

```
//coinChart component's queryFn function

export async function fetchCoinHistory(coinId: string |  undefined) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://ohlcv-api.nomadcoders.workers.dev?coinId=${coinId}`, {method: 'GET'})
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return response.json();
}
```

If throw new Error() was thrown in fetchCoinHistory, it was expected that ErrorBoundary of `Routers.tsx` would detect the error and show `<h1>error occur!</h1>`, the result value of FallbackComponent.
But when the api call throws an error, the browser throws an error like below

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR

Error
    at fetchCoinHistory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1236:11)
```

Suspense's fallback works normally, but ErrorBoundary's FallbackComponent does not work normally. please tell me the cause

I wrote it using Google Translate, so please forgive me :)